# How to read sec-websocket-protocol header with Axum

Tags: rust, websocket, rust-tokio, rust-axum

I'm using Axum with Rust.

In the web socket handler function I want to read custom *sec-websocket-protocol*.
On the [extract](https://docs.rs/axum/0.6.11/axum/extract/index.html#structs) side I couldn't see anything regarding sub-protocol.

Is there any way to access it?

```
async fn ws_handler(
    ws: WebSocketUpgrade,
    ConnectInfo(addr): ConnectInfo<SocketAddr>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
   //want to access sub-protocol here!

    ws.on_upgrade(move |socket| handle_socket(socket, addr))
}
```

Thank you,

I looked https://docs.rs/axum/0.6.11/axum/extract/index.html#structs there. And I couldn't find any variable for it.
I would want to read the sub-protocol value easily if there is a decent way.

Answer (score 0):

To read headers you have to use `axum::http::header::HeaderMap` struct.
So, code will be something like that:

```
use axum::response::IntoResponse;
use axum::{
    extract::ws::{WebSocket, WebSocketUpgrade},
    routing::get,
    Router,
};
use std::net::SocketAddr;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new().route("/ws", get(ws_handler));

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3333));
    axum::Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

async fn ws_handler(ws: WebSocketUpgrade, headers: HeaderMap) -> impl IntoResponse {
    println!("{:?}", headers); // `headers` will contain a map of headers

    ws.on_upgrade(|socket| handle_socket(socket))
}
```